# Log Likelihood for Two Stage Least Squares (for AIC or BIC)

Tags: likelihood, aic, bic, 2sls

I'm looking to use a number of information criteria (BIC, AIC, etc.) for Two Stage Least Squares.

Of course all information criteria need a log likelihood - and I'm also aware that for a Log-Likelihood I need to generally use Maximum Likelihood Estimators.

My question therefore: is there any way that I can get a Log-Likelihood (or actually a BIC/AIC) for two stage least squares estimators?

Thanks!